# "Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data" after upgrading from PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.0

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-4.x, session, error-handling

After upgrading a stable Joomla 3.10.11 website from PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.0, the following error is displayed on the front end and back end of the website:

> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /tmp) in
> /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php on line 260

I have already checked that the appropriate PHP extensions (such as `mysqli`) are enabled in cPanel -> Select PHP Version -> Extensions for PHP 8.0.

I am also seeing the same issue on some of my Joomla 4 websites.

Answer (score 3):

Check and manually update any `Addhandler` directives in the .htaccess file if necessary.

For example, you may need to update:

This: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php74 .php`

To this: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php80 .php`

It seems that cPanel may not update `.htaccess` if the website is a subdomain or in a subdirectory.